# Make Google Cloud Storage Object Public in Elixir

Tags: google-cloud-storage, elixir

I'm using `google_api_storage v0.33.0` with Goth to create objects in the bucket. However created objects don't have public access (I disabled public access of the bucket and want to use object level access). To make them public, I followed guidelines for **GoogleApi.Storage.V1.Api.ObjectAccessControls** - and tried to update acl as

```
GoogleApi.Storage.V1.Api.ObjectAccessControls.storage_object_access_controls_insert(
 conn,
 "example",
 "example.txt",
 "allUsers"
)
```

When executing this logic, I'm getting error 400. I even try with `insert()`, but didn't work.

Is there anything that I'm missing to update object permission? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Make sure to disable uniform bucket-level access if you set an ACL to your object.

Comment: I did that for bucket however I need to enable ACL on object level.

Comment: Are you using this official [docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/create-manage-lists) when you create the ACL on your object? If not, can you provide your reference?